# How to send/receive Gear S3 Custom Heart Rate Monitor (HRM) data to a server

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am using the [Custom Heart Rate Monitor standalone app](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications?langredirect=1) in Samsung S3 Gear. I want to display static/dynamic image from the server first in the watch along with the "start and stop " button.

After the HRM data generated, the data should send to the server. And after successful data passing the HRM App should close automatically in the Watch.

Pls share your thoughts and suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you write any code for getting  static/dynamic image from the server or sending data to server in your app? Define your specific problem.

Comment: @ Yasin shihab I didn't write any code I just used the Tizen Sample App ( https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications?langredirect=1 ) .

Comment: I think you may study different resources of this site like https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides before posting.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you with reading HRM, sending to server and closing the app afterwards.

```
function startHRMSensor() {
  tizen.humanactivitymonitor.start('HRM', onchangedHRValue);
}

function onchangedHRValue(hrmInfo) {
  var hr = hrmInfo.heartRate;
  sendData(hr);
}

function sendData(hr) {
    var API_URL = "https://foobar.foo/endpoint"
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            console.log('done');
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                // exit the app when data is send
                tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
            } else {
                alert("failed to send data!");
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("POST", API_URL);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var data = {
        "key" : "heart_rate",
        "value": hr
    };

    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

window.onload = function() {
    startHRMSensor();
}
```

Comment: where should I add this code, because its giving some errors

Comment: add it to your main `.js` file, it may be named `app.js` or `main.js` something like it

Comment: Cannot find javascript file in that folder

Comment: Did you create native project or WEB? To use this code you need a WEB project.

Comment: Can we make a custom design in Web Project? ie. "Start" and "Stop" button. Its a native project https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications?langredirect=1

Comment: Sure you can make any design you want in both native and web projects. I would say that its even easier in web because you can use html and css for layout.

Comment: Can I get any sample app for that

Comment: You may look through https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/user-interface/tizen-advanced-ui for UI design.

Comment: The Problem I go for Native Application is that Web Application didn't showing accurate result and it also say it cannot read "clean sensor" message coming often

Comment: For native look through https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/native-tools/writing-and-editing-code/ui-builder. I think you may study different resources of this site before posting.